# PHP Security on Forms and DOM Manipulation

Tags: php

I was having an interesting discussion with a fellow co-worker about security in PHP.

Let's say a person has a PHP site running with a standard HTML form. An attacked decides to use Chrome Developer tools and add in the DOM `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and a `file input`.

The attacker uploads a file, it probably won't execute if it were a virus yet it's still using bandwidth/storage for that moment. Would the file go into the PHP `/tmp` directory just by doing this? Wouldn't this make every form some-what insecure as a user can upload a file in any form?

On a bigger scale what if 100,000 people added that to the DOM and uploaded a random gigabyte file? Wouldn't that temporarily make them hit their bandwidth and/or storage mark?

Comment: You will still need some sort of server side code to handle the upload, if it's not there, it wont upload!

Comment: It will automatically go in the `$_FILES['name']['tmp_name']` won't it?

Comment: If you have a hosting provider that charges you for **incoming** bandwidth, please tell them to jump off a bridge. But yes, stuff is automatically stored in `/tmp`, but is recycled over time.

Comment: Good point @SébastienRenauld I see mosts hosts charge for outgoing bandwidth.. This could be a serious DDoS attack if you got a bunch of users uploading files, much worse than pinging a server with a DDoS attack I would think.

Comment: You can disable/regulate form upload size through php.ini. You can also throttle requests or deny them altogether using a load balancer, something every company should do... if they have any sense.

Comment: You don't even need to create any complicated scenarios with Chrome Developer tools... **Anybody can send any arbitrary HTTP request to your server at any time. From anywhere. With any content.** Ain't nobody needing no form and no Chrome Developer tools fo' that. That's the first thing you need to understand about security. Give me a few minutes and I'll throw together a small script that pipes the infinite output of `/dev/random` right into your server in handy 1GB chunks in parallel requests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upload itself happens, no matter what. The file gets stored in the upload temp dir, and then the PHP script is started. If the script does not handle the uploaded file, the file is deleted from the temp dir automatically when the script has finished executing.

Whether the server will abort the request when a maximum size is exceeded, is a matter of configuration.

Comment: Ahh! I forgot about the max file size upload, and timeouts -- I think these are the security measures that will offset this problem!

Comment: If all your upload PHP scripts are located under one directory, then you can control the upload file size using LimitRequestBody in .htaccess file. Put small value for LimitRequestBody (200 KB) in webroor's .htaccess file and under the directory where your upload PHP script resides, give higher value of LimitRequestBody